# Widget Margin vs layout margin

Tags: qt

There is SetContentsMargin both in QWidget and layout. So is that 2 margins getting added or both are operating for the same margin. Take an example where a layout is set to the widget and the margins are set to both the widget and the layout, Is there a standard approach by Qt? And does all the in-built layout of Qt follow that? What is the original idea behind all this?

Answer (score 2):

On the widget the margins are an area within the widget.

So if you have a widget with a size of 100 x 50 and margins of (5,6,5,6), then you will have a `contentsRect()` of `QRect(5,6 90x38)`.

The widget can draw in its margins and as far as `QLayout` is concerned these margins are counted as in the widget. These margins are used to inform other widgets and subclasses of where is the "core" of the widget. This can be useful to tell subclasses where they are allowed to draw.

The margins for layouts are the same. They represent an area within the layout. If you have a layout with a left margin of 10 px, the first widget will render 10 px away from the border of the layout. If this widget has a left margin of 5 px, then the meaningful content of the widget will start 15 px away from the layout border. However, as I said before, the part for 10 px to 15 px is within the widget and the widget can draw in this space.

In layouts you also have `spacing`, as for the margins, it adds up to the widgets margins.

[image]

#### Additional info

If you place a layout inside a widget, the layout will only occupy the content rectangle (`contentsRect()`). Then the layout will have its own margin, counted inside the layout.

To conclude, the total visible margin is the margin of the parent widget + the margin of the layout + the margin of the child widget.

Comment: Appreciate your effort in answering,  but this is not what I asked. In above example, you have layout outside and 2 widgets inside. And you have explained the outer layout's margin and inner widget's margin. My question arises, when you have a layout inside a widget. Take the below code for example: QWidget * ContainerWidget = new QWdget; QGridLayout *ContainerLayout = new QGridLayout(ContainerWidget). Now the total margin inside the ContainerWidget = ContainerWidget's margin or ContainerWidget's margin+ ContainerLayout's margin?